# Where is .htaccess located in ubuntu apache2?

Tags: ubuntu, cache-control

I've already enable headers using command `a2enmod headers`,i want to vim it to edit cache-control allowed http no_cache, just don't know where is `.htaccess` located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.htaccess` is a control file which can be located in arbitrary folder in order to overwrite apache default settings regarding that folder and its subfolders.

Create that file inside the document root of your project and edit it.