# Where to put .htaccess file in Spring project?

Tags: spring, cors, apache2

Following this answer: [Where is .htaccess located in ubuntu apache2?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19398338/7769052), I created an `.htaccess` file in `src/main/resources` directory of my Spring project. However, it doesn't seem to work as it has the following content

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

Then I restarted my computer, but I still have CORS problems. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add an .htaccess file to some directory being accessed on your Apache HTTP Server, you'll have to find some mechanism other than baking it deep inside some maven jar or war file.

Even if the htaccess were unpacked somewhere as part of deployment, If Apache HTTP Server is involved in serving a spring application, it would not be through the filesystem.

Comment: What do you mean by *some mechanism*?

Comment: Some deployment step

Comment: Could you give a concrete example in which deployment step I can add `.htaccess` file and how exactly I can do that, please?

Comment: Copy the htaccess file to a directory being served by Apache that has AllowOverride != None?

Comment: Now you made it clear. In my configuration (`/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`), I find for example `/var/www` as such a directory.